# Insering hyperlinks in Flowplayer

Tags: hyperlink, flowplayer

I would like to insert clickable overlay banners in flowplayer? Is it possible to do it using content plugin: http://flowplayer.org/plugins/flash/content.html

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked states that the Flowplayer Content plugin can be used to "to layout text, images, links and even SWF files over or beside the video screen, " which to me sounds like: Yes, you can make clickable banner ads.

Additionally, Flowplayer supports many advertising services, including AdSense, Doubleclick, and Open Video Ads.